# Is it recommended to keep a program sources (as opposed to lib sources) in a single file?

Tags: go

I am making my first steps into Go and obviously am reasoning from what I'm used to in other languages rather than understanding go specificity and styles yet.

I've decided to rewrite a ruby background job I have that takes ages to execute. It iterates over a huge table in my database and process data individually for each row, so it's a good candidate for parallelization.

Coming from a ruby on rails task and using ORM, this was meant to be, as I thought of it, a quite simple two files program: one that would contain a struct type and its methods to represent and work with a row and the main file to operate the database query and loop on rows (maybe a third file to abstract database access logic if it gets too heavy in my main file). This file separation as I intended it was meant for codebase clarity more than having any relevance in the final binary.

I've [read](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) and [seen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCsL89YtqCs) several things on the topic, including questions and answers here, and it always tends to resolve into writing code as libraries, installing them and then using them into a single file source (in package main) program.

I've read that one may pass multiple files to go build/run, but it complains if there is several package name (so basically, everything should be in `main`) and it doesn't seem that common.

So, my questions are :

- did I get it right, and having code mostly as a library with a single file program importing it the way to go?
- if so, how do you deal with having to build libraries repeatedly? Do you build/install on each change in library codebase before executing (which is way less convenient that what `go run` promise to be) or is there something common I don't know of to execute library dependent program quick and fast while working on those libraries code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Go and the `go` tool works on packages only (just `go run` works on files, but that is a different story): You should not think about files when organizing Go code but packages. A package may be split into several files, but that is used for keeping test code separated and limiting file size or
grouping types, methods, functions, etc.

Your questions:

> did I get it right, and having code mostly as a library with a single file program
>   importing it the way to go?

No. Sometimes this has advantages, sometimes not. Sometimes a split may be one lib + one short main,
in other cases, just one large main might be better.  Again: It is all about packages and never about files. There is nothing wrong with a single 12 file main package if this is a real standalone program. But maybe extracting some stuff into one or a few other packages might result in more readable code. It all depends.

> if so, how do you deal with having to build libraries repeatedly? Do you build/install on each change in library codebase before executing (which is way less convenient that what go run promise to be) or is there something common I don't know of to execute library dependent program quick and fast while working on those libraries code?

The `go` tool tracks the dependencies and recompiles whatever is necessary. Say you have a package main in `main.go` which imports a package foo. If you execute `go run main.go` it will recompile package foo transparently iff needed. So for quick hacks: No need for a two-step  `go install foo; go run main`.  Once you extract code into three packages foo, bar, and waz it might be a bit faster to install foo, bar and waz.

Comment: Ok, thanks. "There is nothing wrong with a single 12 file main package if this is a real standalone program." I guess it was my main problem, I tended to think of a package as a class (not having used java before doesn't help, I guess).

Answer (score 2):

No. Look at the Go commands and Go standard packages for exemplars of good programming style.

[Go Source Code](https://code.google.com/p/go/wiki/Source)